# Kubernetes - How to read logs that are written to files in pods instead of stdout/stderr?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod in a state of `CrashLoopBackOff`, the logs I'm seeing from `kubectl logs <pod-name> -p` present only a partial picutre. Other logs are found in other files (e.g. `/var/log/something/something.log`).

Since this pod is crashed, I can't `kubectl exec` into a shell there and look at the files.

How can I look at the log files produced by a container that is no longer running?

To be more specific, I'm looking for log files file under `$HOME/logs/es.log` (in the container that failed)

Comment: Docker logs are stored on worker nodes under `/var/log/containers/`. Unless you have rotation enabled, these are persisted even if pods aren't running.

Comment: I'm not looking for docker logs. maybe I should have been more clear. The logs I'm looking for are located at $HOME/logs/es.log

Comment: Ah. In that case if the logs aren't written to a persistent volume, there's no way to access them after a container is deleted. Keep in mind however any stdout and stderr output is captured by docker and written to `/var/log/containers/`. So if contents of `$HOME/logs/es.log` were also written to stdout you should be able to access them from the worker node it originally ran on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was so frustrated from finding no solution to this seemingly common problem that I built a docker image that tails log files and sends them to stdout, to be used as a sidecar container.

---

Here's what I did:

1. I added a volume with `emptyDir{}` to the pod
2. I mounted that volume to my main container, with the `mountPath` being the directory to which it writes the logs to
3. I added another container to the pod, called "logger", with the image being the log tracker I wrote (`lutraman/logger-sidecar:v2`), and mounted the same volume to `/logs` (I programmed the script to read the logs from this directory)

then, all the logs written to that directory, can be accessed by `kubectl logs <pod-name> -c logger`

---

Here is an example yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dummy
  labels:
    app: dummy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dummy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dummy
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: logs
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: dummy-app # the app that writes logs to files
          image: lutraman/dummy:v2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: MESSAGE
              value: 'hello-test'
            - name: LOG_FILE
              value: '/var/log/app.log'
          volumeMounts:
            - name: logs
              mountPath: /var/log
        - name: logger # the sidecar container tracking logs and sending them to stdout
          image: lutraman/logger-sidecar:v2
          volumeMounts:
            - name: logs
              mountPath: /logs
```

---

For anyone who is interested, here is how I made the sidecar container:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.9

RUN apk add bash --no-cache

COPY addTail /addTail
COPY logtrack.sh /logtrack.sh

CMD ["./logtrack.sh"]
```

addTail:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

(exec tail -F logs/$3 | sed "s/^/$3: /" ) &
echo $! >> /tmp/pids
```

logtrack.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

trap cleanup INT

function cleanup() {
  while read pid; do kill $pid; echo killed $pid; done < /tmp/pids
}

: > /tmp/pids

for log in $(ls logs); do
  ./addTail n logs $log
done

inotifyd ./addTail `pwd`/logs:n
```

Comment: what about the 'logrotate'?  is that been covered?

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This looks like "Using a sidecar container with the logging agent
" sections in k8s official documentation. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-sidecar-container-with-the-logging-agent

Comment: Similar to @Tun 's question, did you periodically clean up the log file? Since now the log file is duplicated to stdout, it will double the disk usage

Comment: @yusong you are correct, this will double the size on disk during the time the pod is running. For my case it was not very relevant, as the original files were saved in the container's fs, which is ephemeral and will be deleted on each restart (which was frequent enough in my case not to worry about). The other logs are saved to elastic, for which I do have rotation. It is a valid concern if you have large log files and a long time between restarts

Comment: Or you can place stdout in a logback.xml problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have several options here.

### If you want to proceed as is with you setup,

you can access files of exited container from the host where the container run.
Find out the worker the container is on:

```
$ kubectl get pod my-pod -o custom-columns=Node:{.spec.nodeName} --no-headers
my-worker-node
```

Then if you have the access to this node (e.g. via shh) you can find the container:

```
$ ID=$(docker ps -a | grep my-pod | grep -v POD | cut -d" " -f1)
$ docker cp $ID:/my.log .
$ cat my.log
log entry
```

If you don't have ssh access to the node you can use plugins like this one: https://github.com/kvaps/kubectl-enter

### But generally this is not the best practice

You shouldn't write logs into files, instead your app should write in into stdout/stderr, then it would be much easier to debug

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `--previous` flag?

It's like

```
$ kubectl logs <pod-name> <container-name> --previous
```